# INSERT field=LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I wanted to insert a row where one of its field got the ID from an AUTO_INCREMENT field. Is it possible to do this in one single query?

```
INSERT INTO table (`id`, `sameID`) VALUES('', LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

> id | sameID
>
> 1  | iam=1
>
> 2  | iam=2
>
> 3  | this=3
>
> 4  | this=4

Comment: Maybe this can be done with an INSERT trigger. Why do you want to do this? What is the purpose of the `sameId` column?

Comment: It is not EQUAL but yes it is SAME. WORDPRESS has 'GUID' field where its value is same as ID. I wanted to create an auto post by following the format of Wordpress.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible with a single statement. At least not with any version I know.

Comment: In your case, the LAST_INSERT_ID() is an expression that is evaluated *before* the INSERT tries to create the row. So it naturally can't get access to the id which will be generated as the row is created.